# How to make same objects overlap on the texture space for Game Object

Tags: uv

Here I have game object, I have 3 propellers which will have same texture and I want object texture to be optimised so I thought about overlapping them(island on texture space). However, for every object in scene which should have same texture space this can take up some time. What is the fastest way?

Is it good to do it by ALT+D or manually overlapping islands?[image]

Comment: I would say alt d, yeah.

Comment: Only when I want to do some adjustments I have to separate them again

Comment: You shouldn’t have to if they are separate objects but all using the same mesh data: it will carry across.